# T-SQL - OPENXML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-openxml

I have the following SQL code:

```
DECLARE @DocHandle int;
DECLARE @XmlDocument nvarchar(4000);
SET @XmlDocument = N'<ROOT>
<projectId>15468</projectId><projectId>15469</projectId><projectId>15472</projectId> 
<projectId>15849</projectId><projectId>13801</projectId><projectId>13802</projectId>
<projectId>13803</projectId><projectId>15684</projectId><projectId>14044</projectId> 
<projectId>15722</projectId><projectId>15753</projectId><projectId>15770</projectId> 
<projectId>15771</projectId>
</ROOT>';
-- Create an internal representation of the XML document.
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument;
-- Execute a SELECT statement using OPENXML rowset provider.
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, 'ROOT//', 2)
  WITH (projectId  VARCHAR(10));
```

If I run it like this, I only get project id into the first row, the rest are nulls. Any idea to specify the path correctly?

Thanks

Update. Actual code with nodes:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    create table #selectedProjectsList (projectId int)
    create index #idx_selectedProjectsList On #selectedProjectsList 
    (projectId)

    if @params is not null
    BEGIN
        if @params.value('count(//projectId)', 'int') > 0
        BEGIN
          insert into #selectedProjectsList
          select PIDS.PID.value('.', 'int')
          From @params.nodes('//projectId') as PIDS(PID)
        END
    END
```

params is a parameter that looks like this:

```
@params xml = null
```

Comment: Any reason to use that instead of `declare @XmlDocument xml` and `select x.x.value(N'.', 'varchar(10)') from @XmlDocument.nodes(N'/ROOT/projectId') x(x)`?

Comment: I am trying to replace @XmlDocument.nodes that I have currently with something else to troubleshoot the problem. It seems like the server cannot process a very long xml string.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Asl8zO4r

Comment: @Martin. Thats actually did it, thanks. This "VARCHAR(10) '.'" did it.

Comment: If you show the actual query you are doing with `.nodes` we can try and improve it. It's very easy to end up with poor performing XML queries.

Comment: Added actual query.

Comment: OK you can optimize that quite a lot. There is no need for the extra `count` check because `.nodes` will return no rows in that case. The descendant axis `//` is slow, you should use `/ ` instead, also use `text()[1]` instead of `.`. So you need `insert into #selectedProjectsList (projectId) select PIDS.PID.value('text()[1]', 'int') from @params.nodes('/Root/projectId') as PIDS(PID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary issue was that you had the XPath wrong, it should have been `ROOT/projectId`. You then need to change your `WITH` to   `WITH (projectId  VARCHAR(10) 'text()');`. And for defensive coding you need to make sure to release the handle.

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    -- Create an internal representation of the XML document.
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument;
    -- Execute a SELECT statement using OPENXML rowset provider.
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, 'ROOT/projectId', 2) 
    WITH (projectId  VARCHAR(10) 'text()');

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle; 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle; 
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vl-772WN)

But it's much better to use the newer (from 2005!) XML functions, such as `.nodes` and `.value`. Note that they only work on `xml` typed  variables.

```sql
DECLARE @XmlDocument xml = N'<ROOT>
<projectId>15468</projectId><projectId>15469</projectId><projectId>15472</projectId> 
<projectId>15849</projectId><projectId>13801</projectId><projectId>13802</projectId>
<projectId>13803</projectId><projectId>15684</projectId><projectId>14044</projectId> 
<projectId>15722</projectId><projectId>15753</projectId><projectId>15770</projectId> 
<projectId>15771</projectId>
</ROOT>';

SELECT x1.prj.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM @XmlDocument.nodes('ROOT/projectId') x1(prj);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/42xvlZD2)

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid using. I have two servers with the same db. One is running it fine, the other seems like is chocking on XML processing because in reality the XNL string is over 100K.

Comment: No, ROOT/projectId is not working. All rows are nulls.

Comment: @Mark - You also need to change the `WITH` clause as `OPENXML (@DocHandle, 'ROOT/projectId', 2) WITH (projectId  VARCHAR(10))` would match  `<ROOT><projectId><projectId>15468</projectId></projectId></ROOT>`

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Sounds like it might be better to use something to different to process the XML, like Python or C# or Powershell. SQL Server is not really made for processing giant XML

Answer (score 1):

The `ROOT//` returns 27 results.

The `ROOT` element, and 13 `projectId` elements and 13 `#text` nodes.

The only one of those where applying `projectId` in the `WITH` clause returns anything is when it is applied to the `ROOT` node.

You can use

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, 'ROOT/projectId', 2) 
WITH (projectId  VARCHAR(10) '.');
```

Though I'm not sure this will [help or hinder performance](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e51ef84d-72d6-490a-844a-fe28fbea3648/xml-performance-comparison-why-is-openxml-faster?forum=sqlxml) compared to `.nodes`